# Добрый вечер!

Tags: словообразование

Задание из Егэ:
1893. Из пред­ло­же­ний 7-9 вы­пи­ши­те слово, об­ра­зо­ван­ное при­ста­воч­ным спо­со­бом.

(1)Молодой отец стро­го выговаривает четырёхлетней дочке за то, что она вы­бе­жа­ла во двор без спро­су и едва не по­па­ла под машину.

— (2)Пожалуйста, — впол­не серьёзно го­во­рит он крохе, — мо­жешь гулять, но по­ставь в из­вест­ность меня или маму.

(3)Сие — не вы­дум­ка фельетониста, но подлинный, не­на­ро­ком подслушанный разговор.

(4)Или серьёзно пишут в ста­тье о ра­бо­те экипажа кос­ми­че­ской станции: «Производился забор (!) проб вы­ды­ха­е­мо­го воздуха». (5)Этот забор не за­ле­тел бы в космос, если бы не стес­ня­лись сказать попросту: кос­мо­нав­ты брали пробы. (6)Но нет, несолидно!

(7)Слышишь, видишь, чи­та­ешь такое — и хо­чет­ся снова и снова бить в набат, взывать, умолять, уговаривать: БЕ­РЕ­ГИСЬ КАНЦЕЛЯРИТА!

(8)Это — самая распространённая, самая зло­ка­че­ствен­ная болезнь нашей речи. (9)Когда-то ред­кост­ный знаток рус­ско­го языка и чу­до­дей слова Кор­ней Иванович Чу­ков­ский заклеймил её точным, убий­ствен­ным названием. (10)Статья его так и на­зы­ва­лась — «Канцелярит», и про­зву­ча­ла она по­и­сти­не как SOS. (ll)He ре­ша­юсь сказать, что то был глас во­пи­ю­ще­го в пустыне: к счастью, есть рыцари, которые, не щадя сил, сра­жа­ют­ся за честь Слова. (12)Но, увы, надо по­смот­реть правде в глаза: кан­це­ля­рит не сдаётся, он наступает, ширится. (13)Это ока­ян­ный и зло­вред­ный недуг нашей речи. (14)Быстро раз­рас­та­ют­ся чужеродные, гу­би­тель­ные клетки — по­сты­лые штампы, ко­то­рые не несут ни мысли, ни чувства, ни на грош информации, а лишь за­би­ва­ют и угне­та­ют живое, по­лез­ное ядро.

(15)Мы на­столь­ко отравлены канцеляритом, что порою на­чи­сто теряем чув­ство юмора. (16)И уже не в романе, а в жизни, в самой обы­ден­ной обстановке, че­ло­век вполне скром­ный всерьёз го­во­рит другому: «Я вы­ра­жаю вам благодарность».

(17)Помните, у Не­кра­со­ва в Ле­до­ви­том океане лодка утлая плывёт и мо­ло­дой пригожей Тане Вань­ка песенки поёт? (18)Хорошо поёт, собака,
Убе­ди­тель­но поёт...

(19)Да, объ­яс­нять­ся в любви не толь­ко стихами, но и про­зой надо убедительно, иначе Таня Вань­ке не поверит.

(20)А меж тем в сот­нях рассказов, романов, очерков, пе­ре­вод­ных и отечественных, раз­ные люди по раз­ным поводам раз­го­ва­ри­ва­ют так, что кажется: вот-вот чи­та­те­ли отзовутся зна­ме­ни­тым громогласным «Не верю!» Кон­стан­ти­на Сергеевича Станиславского...

(21)В сотый раз спро­сим себя: кто же дол­жен прививать людям вкус, чув­ство меры, бе­реж­ное отношение к род­но­му языку? (22)А за­од­но — и ува­жи­тель­ное отношение к человеку, с ко­то­рым разговариваешь?

(23)Кто, если не мы сами?!
(По Н. Галь*)

*Нoра Галь (настоящее имя Эле­о­но­ра Гальперина; 1912—1991) — вы­да­ю­щий­ся литератор, пе­ре­вод­чик английской и фран­цуз­ской литературы на рус­ский язык.
По­яс­не­ние.
ЗА­КЛЕЙ­МИЛ об­ра­зо­ва­но от гла­го­ла КЛЕЙ­МИТЬ при по­мо­щи при­став­ки за-.

Ответ: за­клей­мил

почему слово умолять и уговаривать не подходит для ответа?

Answer (score 2):

Схема примерно такая)
Заклеймить <-- за + клеймить (приставочный способ). 
**Умолять** <-- умолить (замена суффикса) <-- у + молить.
**Уговаривать** <-- уговорить (замена суффикса) <-- у + говорить. 
В двух последних примерах названные Вами слова образовались суффиксальным способом.

Comment: Если короче,нет слов молять и говаривать(в этом значении), а приставочный способ - когда убираешь приставку и получаешь исходное слово.

Answer (score 0):

> ЗА­КЛЕЙ­МИЛ об­ра­зо­ва­но от гла­го­ла КЛЕЙ­МИТЬ при по­мо­щи при­став­ки за-.

Глаголы прошедшего времени образуются от инфинитива с пом. суф. -Л-. Или я что-то путаю?

Comment: Так образуется ФОРМА слова, а начальная форма глагола - инфинитив, нужно смотреть, как образован инфинитив. Заклеймить= за+ клеймить

Comment: Но в ответе дается слово "заклеймил" как образованное приставочным способом...

Comment: Не пойму, о чем спор: "заклеймил" образовано от "клеймил" с помощью приставки за- . Это приставочный способ.

Comment: Инна, заклеймил, заклеймила, заклеймят, заклейми - все это набор форм одного глагола, одного слова - заклеймить. Этот глагол образован приставочным способом. Суффикс Л в глаголах прошедшего времени образует не новое слово, а форму слова (как окончание), при словообразовательном разборе такие суффиксы не учитываются.  В ответах написана именно та форма, которая употреблена в тексте. Кроме суффикса Л, формообразующими суффиксами являются суффиксы повелительного наклонения, суффиксы причастий и деепричастий, суффиксы степеней сравнения.

Comment: Спасибо. Всю жизнь у меня были неверные сведения.